# Javascript to automatically turn on sound volume on video after autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, controls, video-streaming, html5-video

I am coding an online psychology experiment. Participants have to watch a short movie and remember some information. To analyze the data everyone has to see the same movie, so it would be a problem if people pause it. Therefore, I disabled all controls and autoplay the video.

On Chrome this only works if the player starts mute. So I would like to turn on the sound automatically right after the video starts.

I am trying to use the following html with the video hosted [here](https://muse.ai/docs#embed-player)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
  </head>

  <body style="width: 1000px; height: 800px; background-color: grey;">

    <div class="container">
      <div id="video-player"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://muse.ai/static/js/embed-player.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      const player = MusePlayer({
        container:'#video-player',
        video: 'qhRjheS',
        width: 720,
        height: 480,
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        volume: 0,
        style: 'no-controls',
        shortcuts: false,
        css: '*{pointer-events:none!important;}',
      });
      player.on('timeupdate', function(time) {player.setVolume(100)});
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Where this line is the issue:

```
player.on('timeupdate', function(time) {player.setVolume(100)});
```

This works in the console, while the video is running, but crashes if it's put in the script.

Can anyone think of any way to turn on the sound automatically? If there is a small delay after the movie starts, that would be okay.

Answer (score 1):

As an experiment (not a full solution) I'd try something like this:

```
setTimeout(() => player.on('timeupdate', () => player.setVolume(100)), 3000);
```

(I took the liberty of changing your code to use arrow functions.)

I suspect that the player isn't immediately ready to have the volume set, and takes a moment to be fully set up and ready to go. I'm not familar with MusePlayer specifically, but I'd look at the docs and see if there are other events, besides the `'timeupdate'` event, that you'd want to receive first before setting up the listener for the `'timeupdate'` event.

Comment: Thanks, that suggestion is helpful. The video runs for the 3 seconds set, then pauses, with the following warning in the console: "embed-player.min.js:1 Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before. [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes" I guess unmuting is somehow blocked? Is there possibly a way around?

Comment: It was easy enough for me to paste this code into a CodePen and give a try myself. Instead of a crash, I got this error: "Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before." It might well be that Chrome is protecting users from advertisements that (quite obnoxiously) start playing out loud without the user's permission. That might be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kshetline for the input. It's indeed a problem for me that chrome blocks autoplay. However, adding an event listener to start the movie on click is a workaround. I guess autostart is not possible, but this way all other controls still remain disabled once the movie starts.

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function () {
    player.play();
});
```